# how to decode RTF to HTML in mysql

Tags: html, mysql, ms-access, rtf

i have old database made in MS Access for Visual Basic 6 application. i need to convert it to web app.

one of the field a guest is rtf, how to convert to html, or something like rtf decode

Thank you

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1057{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0 System;}{\f1\fnil\fprq2\fcharset0 MS Sans Serif;}{\f2\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0 Arial;}{\f3\fnil\fcharset0 MS Sans Serif;}}
{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;\red0\green0\blue255;}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\li357\ri357\qc\tx357\tx1077\tx1797\tx2517\tx3238\tx3958\tx4678\b\f0\fs20{\pict\wmetafile8\picw2514\pich2514\picwgoal1425\pichgoal1425 
010009000003711600000000f113000000000400000003010800050000000b0200000000050000
000c0260006000030000001e005f020000410b8600ee005f005f00000000005f005f0000000000
280000005f0000005f000000010001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000ffffff00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007fffff800000000000000003fffffff00
000000000000001fffffff00000000000000001fffffff00000000000000001ffffffe00000000
000000003ffffffe0000000000000000ffffffffc000000000000003fffffffff8000000000000
1ffffffffffc0000000000003fffffffffff0000000000007ff7ffffffff800000000000ffe3ff
ffffffc00000000001ffc3fffff0ffe0000000001fffc1fffff07ff8000000003fff81ffffe07f
fe000000007fff00ffffc07fff00000000ffef00ffffc07fff80000001ffc700ffffc03fffc000
0001fc0380ffffc071ffe0000003f801c07fff80f03ff0000007f001e07fff81e00ff0000007e0
00f07fff87c007f0000001c000ffffff8fc007b00000000000ffffffffc003800000000000ffff
ffffc001800000000000ffffffffc000800000000000ffffffff80000000000000007fffffff80
000000000000007fffffff80000000000000007fffffff0000000000000000ffffffff00000000
0000001fffffffff000000000000007ffffffffff0000000000001ffffffffffffc00000000007
fffffffffffff0000000001ffffffffffffffc000000003ffffffffffffffc00000000ffffffff
ffffffff00000000ffffffffffffffff80000001ffffffffffffffffc0000003ffffffffffffff
ffc0000007ffffffffffffffffe000000ffffffffffffffffff000000ffffffffffffffffff000
000ffffffffffffffffff800001ffffffffffffffffff800001ffffffffffffffffff800003fff
fffffffffffffffc00003ffffffffffffffffffc00003ffffffffffffffffffc00007fffffffff
fffffffffe00007ffffffffffffffffffe00007ffffffffffffffffffe00007fffffffffffffff
fffe0000fffffffffffffffffffe0000ffffffffffffffffffff0000ffffffffffffffffffff00
00ffffffffffffffffffff0000ffffffffffffffffffff0000fffffff9ffffdfffffff0000ffff
fff1ffff8fffffff0000ffffffe0ffff07ffffff0000ffffffc07fff03ffffff00007fffff807f
ff03ffffff0000ffffff003ffe01ffffff0000fffffc003ffe00ffffff0000fffff0001ffe003f
ffff0000ffff80001ffc0007ffff00007ffe00003ffc0001fffe0000fff800007ffc00007ffe00
00fff00007fffc00003ffe0000ffe00000fff800001ffe0000ffc000107ff800000ffe00007fc0
000ffff8000007fc00007f80000ffff0000003fc00007f000007fff0000001fc00003f000003ff
f0000001fc00003f000003fff0000000fc00003f000001bff0000000f800003e00000000200000
00f800001e0000000000000000f000001c00000000000000007000000c00000000000000006000
000c00000000000000006000000400000000000000006000000c00000000000000004000000400
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000f1130000410bc60088005f005f00000000005f005f
0000000000280000005f0000005f00000001000800000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000ffffff009999990099cccc006699cc003366fe009999fe006699fe0033
99cc006666cc0033339900003333009999cc003366990033ccfe00cccccc006666fe000066cc00
3399fe003333fe003366cc00669999006666990099ccfe0099fefe00333366003333cc0066ccfe
0033cccc0033fefe00cccc9900336666003399990066fefe0066cccc0066666600999966006633
cc009966990000666600003366003300cc00333333000000330000339900336633003300660000
66990033009900669966000000fe003300fe00fefefe000033fe006633fe00ccfecc00ccccfe00
99cc990066cc660066cc330066fe000066fe3300fefecc0099fe330099cc330066663300fecccc
0033993300669933000033cc00ccfefe00cc99cc003300330000330000333300000000cc000000
99003300000000006600339966000099cc0099666600cc9999006633660066333300feccfe0000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101000101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
010101010101010101010101000101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101000101010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
010101010101010101000101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
0101010101010101030302161b04160e1b04235116041b1b0c02041502020c0201010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101000101010101010101010101
0101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101171b150d1b081f081b2008080e202a08
1c071f0d0e0e0d0d1c082323150f01010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
010101010101000101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
0101010e1c141c0e081c140e0e081f0e0d0e140e081b0814080e1423080e080201010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101000101010101010101010101010101
01010101010101010101010101010101010101010108081c0e0d1c0e2f1922081920160d1f0808
2f1f1d040808080e08230f01010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
010101000101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
04081f0816150f0f380f34340f340f0f34460f0c0c200d0e082008230101010101010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101000101010101010101010101010101010101
01010101010101010101010101010101010f23200c0f3442383e0f0f34340f340f0f0f0f423737
550f022308192a0101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
0001010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010f02023e3434
0234021534230f3434020f02340223150c26020f34550f02234116390101010101010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101000101010101010101010101010101010101010101
010101010101010101010f020f3734380f020203020234380f34340f0f34340f550f340f380f15
0f0f340f0c232302020f0101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101000101
01010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101460f030f550f0f020252020f0f34
340f0f0302040c04030c03030f3e463437520f0f34343734522323230201010101010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101000101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
0101010f2352340f030f02161e4638380c15081c08082f0e08081c120d08080d15020f38463434
0f0c02374615532d230c0101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101000101010101
01010101010101010101010101010101010101010c230f46020202020f343401021c1c080e120e
040d2208191412080804120e080804020f340f02020f5542021f23410201010101010101010101
010101010101010101010101000101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010d20
2003421f020f340f0f0101010e21081c0708080d120d080d080808082212080e0e1f020f340f34
3402033402141f2323010101010101010101010101010101010101010101000101010101010101
0101010101010101010101010101012008080d08380f0f0f1523010101011b0e1b080808081f0d
0807081f080808080d0e1b082301010101340f0234420808090d41230101010101010101010101
010101010101010101000101010101010101010101010101010101010102162323160d1f080820
0f0220160f0101010101080e081c080d080e0d1414080d12080d081b0815230101010101264642
20080412141f23230f010101010101010101010101010101010101000101010101010101010101
010101010101010f0f0d2a0f0f151f08200808080e15010101010101080e04080d0d1407081908
12141f0d0d0e0e08160101010101012f23080808080d0802192323020201010101010101010101
0101010101010001010101010101010101010101010101010234020b0f34343e0c0d0d081c1b03
0101010101010101080e080d1b0d0a081c091a14080d0d08070d010101010101015008120e080d
150f0f02230f0f2302010101010101010101010101010101000101010101010101010101010101
01010f0f34340239343434343901040d20420101010101010101040e0d1f14080b14120d28081b
280d0e080d010101010101010f081b0e0d02343434340223340f23020101010101010101010101
010101000101010101010101010101010101010f0c34343434160234340f010101040803010101
010101010103120d0d0a20070d0a14200d10190d1b0d150101010101010101140e0c0f0f343434
340203343423230f01010101010101010101010101000101010101010101010101010101011534
3434344202010101010101010120080f01010101010101171f0d120b0d12142a08120d2c080d08
0d0f01010101010101220802010101383434230f3434340f232302010101010101010101010101
00010101010101010101010101010103463434344602010101010101010101011c070f01010101
010101280d14140d0a081c140a141f050d2c16010101010101011b12150f0101010101010f0f34
3434340223020f010101010101010101010100010101010101010101010101010f343846343402
0101010101010101010101081d04390101010101010d0d19080e0b14120a0b0e080a191f1f0101
01010101071208020101010101010101010f3434343402230f0101010101010101010101000101
010101010101010101010138395334340201010101010101010101010101080823020101010101
0d08270d140d0d0a200d140a2a0e1f54010101010f16080e160101010101010101010101343434
34340f0f0101010101010101010101000101010101010101010101010101010f46520101010101
0101010101010101011f080d0820152323231f0d141f2b0d0d4d140d0a1408141f2a010101030d
081c042301010101010101010101010f34340f010f0f0101010101010101010101000101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101202f0b140d081f1f2a0d0d0a
0d23030f0a4b0a270d141a192a23150d1405190d1f510101010101010101010101010f340f0101
010101010101010101010101000101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
010101010101150d0d080d0d14200d1919153834340f103233130a2b0d2a0d0d14140d0d1f1423
02010101010101010101010101010f340101010101010101010101010101000101010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101200d2820080b0b1414230334340f03
0c1a33133333134e19080d1a0d12200a08230301010101010101010101010101010f0101010101
010101010101010101000101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
01010104080d0819200828150f1616150f38460933131a0a45130a0a0d0d0d140d081416010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101000101010101010101010101
01010101010101010101010101010101010101010101281f08120d0d0c0f081f200234343e1332
0a2c0a190a4b3014050d140d0a0502010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
010101010101000101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
01080d2f1928020f1516160d0c3446021a13191a33292c0a4530140d050d080802010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101000101010101010101010101010101
01010101010101010101010101010101010101020a1f08150f14151f271646153b0c1433194513
33331a1929280d140a121601010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
0101010001010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101011e2327
2816030d15160d163e0338153e36320a0a331313332c0a1a0d050d0a2401010101010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101000101010101010101010101010101010101
010101010101010101010c150223232323081402030d230d0d4615310f46381a334b1945333333
1a2c290a0d080d2301010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
000101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010115140e0808140d19192823030d
161f1f0f0c0f150f0f230b3013300a333513330a0a4b0d072a2a2316260c010101010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101000101010101010101010101010101010101010101
0101010c0412040d140d0808500d1926150d1f0d0c02310f46024a00002a4c1a281a333313320a
0a290d2a0a1a050505051a1a162302010101010101010101010101010101010101010101000101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010c0408040d0d0d0d0d0d140d0820030d1f0d1603
0339030200002b0000000a3028331313330a450a28050508091414141410130516231501010101
010101010101010101010101010101000101010101010101010101010101010101010115040804
080808080d0d1f0d0d140d16020d191f033931380f4d0048494849002b1a0a0a3333133028330a
08091a14100809141409141a1a2a23020101010101010101010101010101010101000101010101
0101010101010101010101010104071212040816080d2008080d0d200d15161f2f160f0c153423
000b002b00002e494e33192833331a0a130a1a1412200d1a1a14141a1a1a1a1a0a230101010101
010101010101010101010101000101010101010101010101010101010116080d200d0d0d08080d
14140d0808200a2f02161f191502310f0f0b000a0a00000a142b48134b28191a2c0a320a08080a
140512080d1a14141414361a192302010101010101010101010101010101000101010101010101
01010101010101010d0812070808080d0d0d0d200d200d08081f0215161f030c39460f00001912
0a14101900491a33130a2c0a1a330a0d0a0512090a140507081414141414141a23020101010101
0101010101010101010001010101010101010101010101010108080820140d0808080808200d0d
0d080d0d0d0f040c0c343738340200004d051012140b4d004b13321333333335291412040a1412
0408141a091a141a1a141a192d0201010101010101010101010101000101010101010101010101
01010119140804080808080d0d0d0d0d20140d0d0d0d2a460f34343434343402002b0d14100510
0a490029133333133313330a0d081a0808141a1410141414141a141a1a1a0a2301010101010101
0101010101010001010101010101010101010101040807080d200d2020081c080d0d0d200d2f20
0e08230c02034703470f232b14120512100512144819331a13322935330a0808140d1a1414141a
14091310080505091a1a2a23010101010101010101010101000101010101010101010101010f0d
0d200d0809080d0d0d0d2014080819201b211d044b333533353313324c2a19190a10051f190a0b
16030c0c0c030c0c4f1d1b08080d0d141404050808141409140514050a1f230101010101010101
01010100010101010101010101010101160807080808202008080820140d1f1f0e1d1d22080d13
3313331a2a4e301a000000001414000000000f343434343434340c040e1b1b1c0a140814141a1a
1405051a141a1a1a19230101010101010101010101000101010101010101010101010814200404
0d08040d0d0d1420200d08211b1c14080d4b1333131a00494c0a004d2b001f192b4d0b000f3434
3434343434161412141b211b141a1409120414141414140905130a2a2301010101010101010101
0001010101010101010101011f0d1222080808200d0804080d0d1f22211c0808081c1c1a331333
1a19000a0a00004900002b4a2b0000192d2a2a020f3434151c041412080e1d08141a1a1413091a
141a131a0a050a23010101010101010101010001010101010101010101012f04080d1408041404
0d200d1f08210e120808040e0e082933131a190b4828302b2b2b48002a2b00002a162d2d163434
3434041b0e070814071b040a05120708081407140805131a1a1f01010101010101010101000101
01010101010101010f0814040e1b081c08080808080d1c1d220d080e1d221c0d1a131a1a142a2b
2a281a1a29451a3903030c150c231f23380f343404081b1d071214081d1b0d14141314131a1a1a
0d14051a1924010101010101010101000101010101010101010119081b080808090d0d0d0d081f
08210e0808080e0808211b334519140d2b002b000a3513333646340c4703230b2a0b1f16153415
0e0e041d1b0807071d040d07080408041209131a0a1a1a16010101010101010101000101010101
010101010108080d14150808080808200d0d0e1b081c0821201c1d1d0d0a0a190a2b000b002b19
3033330542382a43441f232d2a2d2d2a340c1c1b08081b0e12141b0e140d1a1a1a1a1414141209
0a0a230101010101010101010001010101010101010103140d040e08080820080d081f1c210e08
080e2008210e070d2c191a13291a301a132c19353305340f3b3a3a3f3d3d313b3b31341505121b
0e0d1b0e07121b08140507120705051a0a14051a41020101010101010101000101010101010101
0116081208201415140814150d0d1d1b1c12211420210e0808080a2f293313321333331a0a2933
2534343b3b3a3f3d403a3a3b3934040804081b08081b1208071b0d14141414080405101a0a130a
24010101010101010100010101010101010101151b200d0412080e081c080808210808041c081d
1b08081c1229191a3533133313331a0a1332363e34223b3d3b3a3a3a3d3b0f34150e12121b1b08
081b12080e040a14141a1a1a0d1412360a0a160101010101010101000101010101010101011b0d
0d0408080d160d140d191c210e1b0e081c2108080821081a0a1a333333133335302c3333103834
34393b3c3d3d3d3b033434040e1b08080e22141c07121b12201204121214131a0a1a050a230101
0101010101010001010101010101010f0a070e080d0d0808200808201d0e08080e0d1c1d08040e
21081a0a133313133313331a0a333536373434343803393a3938343434151d1b12081b1b081b12
0412040a1a0a1a0a081208131a0a132301010101010101010001010101010101010f08080d0d07
0e080808080d271b0e040e22201d1b08081d1d0833133313333213331333133333103434343434
343434343434343404221d0712121d04080e14121b0814080505290a1408051a0a0d0201010101
0101010001010101010101010f121f080e1c20140d0d0d1f081d1b081208082108081c21210829
1332331313333333133213322534343434343434343434343434041d1b0e10081b0e071b04051b
0d141414220e091a0d14050a2a0201010101010101000101010101010101170d121b080d141608
1c08080d210e1c1b08082112081b1d1d1b08081c080a0a0a0d2c0a1a0a140a1504160215020202
150c020c15160e211b08040e1b200e10120e081a141a1a14080e130a0a131f2601010101010101
0001010101010101010c141b0d0d09080808141619201d12040e20081d08080e21211d1d0e0403
1619190b191f1f0d140d0d0d0d2c0d0a2828081b0e0e1b0e210e0e12081b0e141b08141b140814
12141a1a1404050a1a2531010101010101010001010101010101010f0e0d140808200d0d160808
08210e081b0e1b2107040e211d211b1f020101281919280a28281f0b0d0d0d0d1f280a0a160301
171d1b0e211b0414071b081b04121b080a1a0a0808101a0a14050a0a2301010101010101000101
01010101010117140d04080d09090808080d1f0e1b0808081c1d08080e211d1d0d020101010d28
191f0a1f190a0a280a191419190a0d0f010101170e210e0e04080e22080e071407080804143014
08051a1a1405192401010101010101000101010101010101140d071216140808080d0d0d082108
081b08082108080e21211c2301010101011928191f280a1f0d1f2a2c2a0a280a1601010101011b
0e211b12070e08041b05121b0d1a1408120a0a1412250a141a2301010101010101000101010101
0101010c12081f1408080d160d0804200821221c080d1d0408221d0e23010101010101010b2a2c
1f0b0a192f192a0a282a28020101010101010e1b0e08141b1b081214090e08141a1a1422050a14
051a1a13020101010101010100010101010101010101120d1404081f0d081c1c0d191c0e08070e
1c211c081d0e200101010101010101022819190d280d2e280d280d2b230f010101010101221d1b
14140e08081b141204141b081a1a1a1c100a14100a1a1601010101010101000101010101010101
07140d12080a14080e0d0a1f0d21211208080e211d1d1c0c010101010101010101010d2819190d
0b1f280d0a1f19230101010101010101040e1b081b1b0e0708120e191a081b141a1a08050a1405
2a0201010101010101000101010101010101140d07040d14221c1f0a0d080e201c1b201b211d1b
04010101010101010101010101191f191f28192a19281f2c2d23010101010101010101220e2121
0e1b0814071b0d1a1a0d0e091a0a04130d130a020101010101010100010101010101010114081c
0d0d1b080d14150e1c0d0a210e1d0e1c170101010101010101010101010101012b19280a19280b
190a0d0d160101010101010101010101171b0e2114100e0d080e0d130a0e12130d100d1a140201
01010101010100010101010101010116070819071c1916080e20191f081d1c0301010101010101
010101010101010101010128282a19282a19281f191f010101010101010101010101010101220e
0e1b0d0a0d07141a0a22051a14050a1a0201010101010101000101010101010101011219081d0d
14081c0d0a0d1c080c010101010101010101010101010101010101010f200a27190a2819191908
0d01010101010101010101010101010101011c21141a1a0d1c09291404051a091a0a0101010101
01010100010101010101010117140d210d0d150e0d0d150e040101010101010101010101010101
010101010101262323080e080e20080d081c16010101010101010101010101010101010101010e
121a1a0a1c051a201b1a141a230101010101010101000101010101010101170d071c0d090e0d16
080e0201010101010101010101010101010101010f221b1b0815081b1d21210e1d0e1b1f020101
010101010101010101010101010101010101081c1a130d1b1a2512100a05160101010101010101
0001010101010101010f0d0e20141b081f080e0c01010101010101010101010101010101010101
0101171b1c0e1d211d12211d1b142301010101010101010101010101010101010101010101080e
1a1a14121a0d12141a020101010101010101000101010101010101030d040a08121f140e150101
010101010101010101010101010101040101010101211b081b0e210e0821080d16010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010104121a0d04050a071a0a0c0101010101010101000101
0101010101010104080d1b200a0e08020101010101010101010101010101010101010808040409
0812071b08080e040e0d0d240101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101011c071a
14121a0d120a010101010101010101000101010101010101010714081b0a080e23010101010101
01010101010101010101010101031408080e1d1b12080e081b080e0d0d01010101010101010101
01010101010101010101010101010101121a1a1c100a0516010101010101010101000101010101
01010101040d12200d0e2001010101010101010101010101010101010101010103200822080820
1b210e0e081b1223010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101120a0912
1a140901010101010101010100010101010101010101011f120d040e1601010101010101010101
0101010101010101010101010c080e080d1f200e2108081d201601010101010101010101010101
0101010101010101010101010101070514121a0a02010101010101010101000101010101010101
01010d1b0d12080201010101010101010101010101010101010101010101150e0e1c0e0808081d
0e1d0e141601010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101050a0413191e
010101010101010101000101010101010101010104140d0e150c01010101010101010101010101
010101010101010101011516011717170e1718170e190f01010101010101010101010101010101
010101010101010101010101051a08051601010101010101010101000101010101010101010103
110412020101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
03010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010108130a100301010101
0101010101010001010101010101010101010d080e0f0101010101010101010101010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
01010101010101010103050d1001010101010101010101010001010101010101010101010b0507
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
01010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101050a0c0101010101010101
010101000101010101010101010101010808010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
01010101010101050a010101010101010101010101000101010101010101010101010708010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010509010101010101010101010101
000101010101010101010101010104010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
010101010506010101010101010101010101000101010101010101010101010304010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010401010101010101010101010101000101
010101010101010101010102010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101000101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101000101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
010101010101010101010101000101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101000101010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
01010101010101010100040000002701ffff030000000000
}\cf1\lang1033\b0\f1\fs16\par
\par
\cf0\f2\fs20\par
\cf2\b PROKLAMASI KEMERDEKAAN REPUBLIK INDONESIA\par
\pard\li357\ri357\qj\tx357\tx1077\tx1797\tx2517\tx3238\tx3958\tx4678\cf0\b0\par
\par
Kami bangsa Indonesia dengan ini menjatakan Kemerdekaan Indonesia. \par
\par
Hal-hal jang mengenai pemindahan kekoeasaan dan lain-lain diselenggarakan dengan tjara seksama dan dalam tempo jang sesingkat-singkatnja. \par
\par
\par
\pard\li4678\ri357\qj\tx357\tx1077\tx1797\tx2517\tx3238\tx3958\tx4678 Djakarta, hari 17 boelan 8 tahoen 1945\par
\par
Atas nama bangsa Indonesia,\par
\par
\ul\b SOEKARNO/HATTA\par
\pard\cf1\lang1057\ulnone\b0\f3\fs16\par
}
```

Comment: Did you try [this rtf-html-php library](https://github.com/henck/rtf-html-php)?

Comment: I'm sory, i think i need to convert it direct in mysql. update the field it self @KoalaYeung

Comment: Someone seems to have wrote [a DLL libraray for this](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?79,401729,401729). I have no idea how it works or if it works. But it worth take a look.